# In Refinery CMS, how can I configure my app to display PDF files in the browser rather than prompting user to download?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, refinerycms

When I click on a PDF link in my local dev version of my Refinery app, the PDF opens in the browser. However, in the test version of my app running on a remote server on Apache, I am prompted to download the file. As far as I can tell, both applications are configured identically.

The difference is that the Apache version returns the `Content-Disposition` header with an `attachment` value:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; privacy.pdf
```

I've followed suggestions from the sites below (which includes Refinery docs) with no success:

- http://refinerycms.com/guides/resources
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/refinery-cms/97ckptiy0ss

I'm on Refinery version 2.0.10.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this successfully with:

```
Refinery::Resources.configure do |config|
  config.content_disposition = :inline  # added to support S3 hosted PDFs as previewable
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added that line to the end of my `config/initializers/refinery/resources.rb` file and restarted Apache, but the PDF file I uploaded still gets delivered as an attachment.